# SSLSocket duplex close failed

Tags: java, ssl, socketexception

I am getting following exception:

> ```
> javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|79|Keep-Alive-Timer|2021-03-29 23:34:12.355 PDT|SSLSocketImpl.java:479|duplex close of SSLSocket<br>
> javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|79|Keep-Alive-Timer|2021-03-29 23:34:12.356 PDT|SSLSocketImpl.java:1569|close the underlying socket<br>
> javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|79|Keep-Alive-Timer|2021-03-29 23:34:12.356 PDT|SSLSocketImpl.java:1588|close the SSL connection (initiative)<br>
> javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|79|Keep-Alive-Timer|2021-03-29 23:34:12.356 PDT|SSLSocketImpl.java:727|close inbound of SSLSocket<br>
> javax.net.ssl|WARNING|79|Keep-Alive-Timer|2021-03-29 23:34:12.356 PDT|SSLSocketImpl.java:500|SSLSocket duplex close failed (
> "throwable" : { 
>     java.net.SocketException: Socket is closed
>   at java.base/java.net.Socket.shutdownInput(Socket.java:1538)
>       at java.base/sun.security.ssl.BaseSSLSocketImpl.shutdownInput(BaseSSLSocketImpl.java:216)
>       at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.shutdownInput(SSLSocketImpl.java:742)
>       at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.bruteForceCloseInput(SSLSocketImpl.java:692)
>       at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.duplexCloseOutput(SSLSocketImpl.java:553)
>       at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.close(SSLSocketImpl.java:485)
>       at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.closeServer(HttpClient.java:1058)
>       at java.base/sun.net.www.http.KeepAliveCache.run(KeepAliveCache.java:183)
>       at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
>       at java.base/jdk.internal.misc.InnocuousThread.run(InnocuousThread.java:134)
> }
> ```

I am really puzzled about where is this error came out.

Comment: It 'came out' because you tried to shutdown a socket that you had already closed. The error message is quite clear.

Answer (score 3):

I experienced this behavior with openJDK11 and above, it seems due to the new implementation of SSL/TLS channel in Java 11 in order to support TLSv1.3. The error it is noticed when it is called a server that supports also TLSv1.3, the JVM tries to open a channel using this protocol with no luck, evidently it is not fully supported yet.

I found a workaround (useful in OpenJDK11) by forcing TLSv1.2, just add the following options to JVM at application startup: `-Djdk.tls.client.protocols=TLSv1.2 -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2`

Notice that this solution does not always work, it depends also by your java code and used libs.

A second way is to downgrade to Jdk1.8, that in default builds does not support TLSv1.3, but it is not always possible.

If you want to investigate more in detail the TLS handshake add also the following JVM parameter at startup: `-Djavax.net.debug=ssl` (for more details set it to `all`)

### Edit

I initially experienced this error in Jenkins on openJDK11 during updates in "add-on manager" from 02/2021, when the repository added the support to TLSv1.3 (https://updates.jenkins.io). During the investigation of the issue I found and tried with jdk11 the following code [from jenkins issue report](https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-63506?workflowName=JNJira%20%2B%20In-Review&stepId=6):

```
 public class DownloadWebpageExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try  {
            URL url = new URL("https://updates.jenkins.io/download/plugins/plugin-util-api/1.2.5/plugin-util-api.hpi");
            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            readStream(con.getInputStream());
            // Give output for the command line
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    private static void  readStream(InputStream in)
    {
        char[] buf = new char[1024];
        try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));) {
            while (reader.read(buf, 0, 1024) != -1) { }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

by running it with `java -Djavax.net.debug=ssl DownloadWebpageExample` it gives the error as above:

```
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2021-06-11 12:40:59.499 CEST|SSLSocketImpl.java:636|close inbound of SSLSocket
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|01|main|2021-06-11 12:40:59.501 CEST|SSLSocketImpl.java:494|SSLSocket duplex close failed (
"throwable" : {
  java.net.SocketException: Socket is closed
        at java.base/java.net.Socket.shutdownInput(Socket.java:1521)
```

By executing it with `java -Djdk.tls.client.protocols=TLSv1.2 -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2 -Djavax.net.debug=ssl DownloadWebpageExample` does not solve the problem.
I tried this code with many jdk versions and I found that jdk8 and openJDK9 are not affected by this behaviour, but it is in openJDK11-16.
In Jenkins I noticed a different behaviour, by adding the parameters in `/etc/sysconfig/jenkins` file like the following solved the problem with openJDK11. For me it is the confirmation that the error it is also dependent by source code implementation:

```
JENKINS_JAVA_OPTIONS="-Djava.awt.headless=true -Djdk.tls.client.protocols=TLSv1.2 -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2"
```

Comment: Evidence please.

Answer (score 0):

Was looking for the same thing, found https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8255148 which indicates that this logging is misleading.

Comment: Different message. Your link is about 'socket is not connected'. Not relevant.

Comment: I am facing the same problem with slightly different error details. Also, I am using OracleJDK HotSpot. Does that make a difference? See https://stackoverflow.com/q/77923895/4180447.