# Error java.net.SocketException: Socket is closed when closing AS400 Secure RPC session

Tags: java, ssl, ibm-midrange, rmi

The Java application (running on Windows) was working fine using `com.ibm.as400.access.AS400`. This application will perform RPC on IBM i.

This Java application was modified to use encrypted SSL connections and all references to this class were changed to use `com.ibm.as400.access.SecureAS400` instead.

Initial testing was successful however, when shutting down the application, the program calls `disconnectAllServices()`, and we see an exception thrown in the console.

Following is the code snippet used to explain the flow. Note that I extracted parts of the code that reference the object `SecureAS400`, and the order of execution may not be correct:

```
import com.ibm.as400.access.SecureAS400;
import com.ibm.as400.access.ProgramCall
...
private SecureAS400 system;
...
system = new SecureAS400(host, user, pwd);
system.connectService(SecureAS400.COMMAND);
ProgramCall pc = new ProgramCall(system);
job = pc.getServerJob();
job.setJobMessageQueueFullAction(Job.MESSAGE_QUEUE_ACTION_WRAP);
if (priority.intValue() > 0) {
  job.setRunPriority(priority.intValue());
  job.commitChanges();
}
...
...
//Process Message
CharacterFieldDescription srcDta = new CharacterFieldDescription(
                new AS400Text(254, system), "SRCDTA");
...
String filePath = (new QSYSObjectPathName(workLibrary, fileName, "FILE")).getPath();
SequentialFile seqFile = new SequentialFile(system, filePath);
RecordFormat recFmt = null;
recFmt = new RecordFormat(fileName);
recFmt.addFieldDescription(...);
recFmt.addFieldDescription(...);
recFmt.addFieldDescription(srcDta);
seqFile.close();
seqFile.delete();
...
...
//Begin
private ProgramCallDocument pcml;
...
pcml = new ProgramCallDocument(system, pcmlFile);
pcml.setValue("lansaexec.lansapgmlib", lansaPgmLibrary);
pcml.setValue(...);
pcml.setValue(...);
...
pcml.callProgram("lansacc")
...
//Commit
pcml.setValue("lansacc.command", flag ? "CMT" : "RLB");
pcml.callProgram("lansacc")
...
//Close connection
pcml.setValue("lansacc.command", "END");
pcml.callProgram("lansacc");
system.disconnectAllServices();
```

Following is what we see in the console log:

```
javax.net.ssl|FINE|52|RMI TCP Connection(7) CST|null:-1|close the SSL connection (initiative)
javax.net.ssl|FINE|52|RMI TCP Connection(7) CST|null:-l|close inbound of SSLSocket
javax.net.ssl|FINE|39|AS400 Read Daemon [system:machine.name.local;job419838/QUSER/QZRCSRVS] nu11:-1|Received alert message (
"Alert": {
  "level"   : "warning"
  "description": "close_notify"
}
)
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|52|RMI TCP Connection:- CST|null:-1|SSLSocket duplex close failed (
"throwable" : {
  java.net.SocketException: Socket is closed
    at java.net.Socket.shutdownInput(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.BaseSSLSocketImpl.shutdownInput(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.shutdownInput(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.bruteForceCloseInput(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.duplexCloseOutput(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.close(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.as400.access.SocketContainerJSSE.close (SocketContainerJSSE.java:69)
    at com.ibm.as400.access.AS400ThreadedServer.forceDisconnect (AS400ThreadedServer.java:258)
    at com.ibm.as400.access.AS400ImplRemote.disconnectServer (AS400implRemote.java:459)
    at com.ibm.as400.access.AS400ImplRemote.disconnect(AS400implRemote.java:431)
    at com.ibm.as400.access.AS400.disconnectAllServices(AS400.java:1412)
    at com.***.***.server.iseries.iSeriesSessionImpl.close(iSeriesSessionImpl.java:307)
    at com.***.***.server.ATASServiceImpl.close(ATASServiceImpl.java:560)
    at com.***.***.server.ATASServiceimpl_Skel.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.OldDispatch(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$l.run (Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$l.run (Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall (Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handlemessages(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.rune(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$e (Unknown Source)
    java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(Unknown Source)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
```

Any idea what is wrong? How we can troubleshoot this error? Can we just ignore the error since the connection is closed anyway?

## Update 1:

I also noticed the same error when the SSL Connection is opened in `com.ibm.as400.access.AS400.connectService()`:

```
javax.net.ssl|FINE|36|RMI TCP Connection(2)-ip-address|date-time CST|null:-1|duplex close of SSLSocket
javax.net.ssl|FINE|36|RMI TCP Connection(2)-ip-address|date-time CST|null:-1|close the underlying socket
javax.net.ssl|FINE|36|RMI TCP Connection(2)-ip-address|date-time CST|null:-1|close the SSL connection (initiative)
javax.net.ssl|FINE|36|RMI TCP Connection(2)-ip-address|date-time CST|null:-1|close inbound of SSLSocket
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|36|RMI TCP Connection(2)-ip-address|date-time CST|null:-1|SSLSocket duplex close failed (
"throwable" : {
  java.net.SocketException: Socket is closed
        at java.net.Socket.shutdownInput(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.BaseSSLSocketImpl.shutdownInput(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.shutdownInput(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.bruteForceCloseInput(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.duplexCloseOutput(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.close(Unknown Source)
        at com.ibm.as400.access.SocketContainerJSSE.close(SocketContainerJSSE.java:69)
        at com.ibm.as400.access.AS400NoThreadServer.forceDisconnect(AS400NoThreadServer.java:245)
        at com.ibm.as400.access.AS400ImplRemote.signonDisconnect(AS400ImplRemote.java:2548)
        at com.ibm.as400.access.AS400ImplRemote.disconnect(AS400ImplRemote.java:422)
        at com.ibm.as400.access.AS400.signon(AS400.java:4212)
        at com.ibm.as400.access.AS400.connectService(AS400.java:1336)
        at com.***.iseries.iSeriesSessionImpl.open(iSeriesSessionImpl.java:246)
        at com.***.***SServiceImpl.initiate(***SServiceImpl.java:379)
        at com.***.***SServiceImpl_Skel.dispatch(Unknown Source)
        ...}
)
```

Per this bug report on OpenJDK:

https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8255148

This is a feature of SSL logging and can be ignored.

I am not sure the same allies to any JDK release and falvores. I see the output of the Java properties:

```
C:>java -XshowSettings:properties -version
...
    java.runtime.name = Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment
    java.runtime.version = 1.8.0_321-b07
    java.specification.name = Java Platform API Specification
    java.specification.vendor = Oracle Corporation
    java.specification.version = 1.8
    java.vendor = Oracle Corporation
    java.vendor.url = http://java.oracle.com/
    java.vendor.url.bug = http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/
    java.version = 1.8.0_321
    java.vm.info = mixed mode
    java.vm.name = Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM
    java.vm.specification.name = Java Virtual Machine Specification
    java.vm.specification.vendor = Oracle Corporation
    java.vm.specification.version = 1.8
    java.vm.vendor = Oracle Corporation
```

Also, I found out that Oracle JDK has a similar issue per this link:

https://knowledge.broadcom.com/external/article/252935/sslsocket-duplex-close-failed-messages-i.html

And, the solution is to remove the logging JVM switch:

`-Djavax.net.debug=ssl:handshake:verbose`

Comment: I think so. `disconnectAllServices()` is closing all known sockets, well at least the socket that the RMI call that invokes it is being made on. You could try starting a thread with a small delay to call `disconnectAllServices()`, and return from the remote method immediately.

Comment: I'm not quite following you could you please explain?

Comment: Explain? I *did* explain. What part of it didn't you understand?

Comment: Please bear with me it was a long day. It worked fine using `com.ibm.as400.access.AS400` so what could have gone wrong when using `SecureAS400`? You are saying to start a process in the background to run `disconnectAllServices()` and I'm thinking why a delay and disconnecting the services in another thread would solve the problem. Maybe the `SecureAS400` has some defaults that will close the connection implicitly. The RPC was completed successfully but the socket was closed somewhere else. So how the delay and using a thread is going the solve the problem?

Comment: The remote method machinery closed this socket while `disconnectAllServices()` was executing. You want to give it a chance to run *first,* not concurrently.

Comment: My understanding is this: Java code sent a command to end the connection using `pcml.setValue("lansacc.command", "END"); pcml.callProgram("lansacc");` so we can try ending the connection using `disconnectAllServices()` without sending the `END` command. Is my understanding correct? I don't understand how the `disconnectAllServices()` is running concurrently as you mentioned.

Comment: Per OpenJDK https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8255148 this is a logging feature of SSL and it can be ignored. It is not clear to me if this applies to all JDK releases.